# Hosted Images with react-pdf

Tags: reactjs, pdf, react-pdf

[Here](https://react-pdf.org/repl) is a `react-pdf` example, and `https://storage.googleapis.com/cbb_logos/conf_logos/conf-1-logo.png` is a link to an image that is publicly hosted on GCS. Per GCS, *"Anyone with this link can access the object on the public internet"*

However, if i copy the link into line 11 in the `react-pdf` example, the image does not display. Per the [docs](https://react-pdf.org/components#image) for their image component, it clearly says: *A React component for displaying network or local (Node only) JPG or PNG images, as well as base64 encoded image strings.*

Simply put, am I out of luck on this, or is there another way to get hosted images in react-pdf?  Perhaps another JS library is better for this? I don't think it's a good idea to save this image locally to my app, as I have 1000 more logos and that would increase my apps size by quite a bit.

**Edit1:** I gave a quick try using jsPDF using this stackblitz (not mine) https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-w5qb9a?file=src%2FApp.js

I dropped this div

```
<div style={{ maxWidth: '40px' }}>
    <img
        style={{width: '100%' }}
        src='https://storage.googleapis.com/cbb_logos/conf_logos/conf-1-logo.png' 
    />
</div>
```

...under the p-tag, then downloaded the PDF, and the image **also did not appear.** So I am still looking for a solution.

Answer (score 7):

I confirmed this works in a project as the docs say, but it doesn't work for some reason on their own [example site](https://react-pdf.org/repl), as you noted.

To test, I created a new react project using `create-react-app`:

```sh
yarn create react-app react-pdf-image
```

Install `react-pdf`:

```sh
cd react-pdf-image
yarn add @react-pdf/renderer
```

**Note**: A new version of `create-react-app` was just released (5.0.0) which uses webpack v5, and at the moment some packages like `react-pdf` no longer work out of the box. I had to add additional configuration to webpack via the `craco` package.

Install additional packages:

```sh
yarn add process browserify-zlib stream-browserify util buffer assert @craco/craco
```

Change the `scripts` section in `package.json` as below:

```js
  "scripts": {
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "craco build",
    "test": "craco test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

Next create a new file in the root of the project `craco.config.js` with these contents:

```js
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  webpack: {
    configure: {
      resolve: {
        fallback: {
          process: require.resolve("process/browser"),
          zlib: require.resolve("browserify-zlib"),
          stream: require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
          util: require.resolve("util"),
          buffer: require.resolve("buffer"),
          asset: require.resolve("assert"),
        },
      },
      plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
          Buffer: ["buffer", "Buffer"],
          process: "process/browser",
        }),
      ],
    },
  },
};
```

Hopefully this issue will be resolved and if so I'll remove these extra steps.

Finally, replace the contents of the `src/App.js` file with this code:

```js
import { Document, Image, Page, PDFViewer, Text } from "@react-pdf/renderer";

const MyDocument = () => {
  return (
    <Document>
      <Page>
        <Text>Image test</Text>
        <Image src="https://storage.googleapis.com/cbb_logos/conf_logos/conf-1-logo.png" />
      </Page>
    </Document>
  );
};

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <PDFViewer>
      <MyDocument />
    </PDFViewer>
  </div>
);

export default App;
```

Back in the root of the project, run `yarn start` and you should see the rendered PDF with the text and image.

Answer (score 2):

06/2022
For those who are trying to solve it, in addition to liquidki comment, what I had to do:

1: Follow every step of liquidki comment.

2: Add the following libraries:

```
yarn add browserify-fs node-polyfill-webpack-plugin process
```

3: In your craco.config.js, add:

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const NodePolyfillPlugin = require("node-polyfill-webpack-plugin")

module.exports = {

  webpack: {
    configure: {
      resolve: {
        fallback: {
          process: require.resolve("process/browser"),
          zlib: require.resolve("browserify-zlib"),
          stream: require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
          util: require.resolve("util"),
          buffer: require.resolve("buffer"),
          asset: require.resolve("assert"),
          fs: require.resolve('browserify-fs'),
        },
      },
      plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
          Buffer: ["buffer", "Buffer"],
          process: "process/browser.js",
        }),
        new NodePolyfillPlugin(),
      ],
      
    },
    
  },
  
};
```

Now restart your app and it should be working.

Answer (score 0):

```js
  function returnSrc() {
    const path =  "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GhNkZlYA7Qu9ZHeXoxsJczf3OPuyyNzLi_hFbgEKnU=s96-c";
    console.log("LOG", path);
    let selectedMethod = "GET";
    return { uri: path, method: selectedMethod, body: "", headers: "" };
  }
```

```html
<Image style={styles.profile} src={returnSrc()} />
```

Comment: While this does display an image on the example site, when I replaced the ```path``` above with the png file in the question, it displays just white space.